# Are fonts always loaded by browsers?

Tags: css, http, browser, fonts, loading

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);


.hi{
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Does the browser load the font even if there's no element with the .hi class in the current page? I know that it doesn't do it for background images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Conde's answer is right, but there's some details that you might want to notice.

1. When it comes to `@font-face` he is right, it will be downloaded only **if there's an html element meeting a css rule that uses the font**. That is so because css properties are only executed as soon as an element meets the selector.
2. But you are not using `@font-face`, you are using `@import`, so be careful. The `@import` is executed no matter what. It is linked to the css file and will be downloaded.
3. But, in your case, you are downloading from google fonts, so the resulting import will be a `@font-face` declaration. Which leads to the first statement.

**Conclusion:**

In other words, in your particular example, the import will be executed. You will request Google's server for it's `@font-face` declaration. But **the actual font file (.ttf, .woff) will not be downloaded** until you really applies the css rule to an Html element.

Answer (score 2):

Unused font that needs to be downloaded [will *not* be downloaded](http://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/) so declaring them but never using them will not hurt performance.

Comment: what does unused mean? on that page is says that = not applying the font family. What if I'm applying it but not using the class on which it's applied?

Comment: How do you apply it without using the class? If you don't use the class it isn't applied.